# cant set variable data inside the each loop

Tags: php, laravel

I want to set a data to a variable after a loop. But it still empty even I assign the variable inside the loop.

My code:

```
$hash = '';

$get_hash = Cart::session($user->id)->getContent()->each(function($cart) use($hash) {

    $hash = $cart->attributes->get('hash');
});

dd($hash) // returns empty
```

I want to set the hash from the value of `$cart->attributes->get('hash')` I don't know why it's empty
but when I `dd` inside the loop there's a value.

Comment: Aren't you looping more than one time, and in the second pass you assign a new empty value ? (maybe because the method return an empty value)

Comment: no, all the items does have the value of hash

Comment: when I echo inside the loop, it's showing all the hash of every item

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The hash variable is not caught by reference:

```php
$hash = '';

$get_hash = Cart::session($user->id)->getContent()->each(function($cart) use (&$hash) {
    $hash = $cart->attributes->get('hash');
});

dd($hash) // will not be empty
```

Scalar values like strings and integers are copied by value, not by reference. By explicitly doing so, changing the hash value in the closure will translate outside the scope.

Comment: wow @Transitive it works, Thank you! wow, will accept your answer after the interval

Comment: No problem! Don't forget to mark this answer as a solution so the issue is closed. Have a great day

Comment: Have a great day too

Comment: This is what, how does it work with **&** https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php